# Blender doesn't recognize '-P' or '--python' command line argument when called with subprocess.run()

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to run a headless Blender from inside a Python program. I intend to have Blender run another Python program after it opens a file.

I can make this work from the command line as such

```
D:\Documents\Programming\████████>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\blender.exe" "kitchen table.blend" -b -P animate_book.py -- "./███████/███████/scripts/chapter-001.csv"
Blender 3.6.0 (hash c7fc78b81ecb built 2023-06-27 08:27:30)
Read prefs: "C:\Users\████████\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\config\userpref.blend"
Read blend: "D:\Documents\Programming\█████████\kitchen table.blend"
Info: Total files 73 | Changed 29 | Failed 0
Info: Saved "chapter-001.blend"
```

This works as expected, opening in background mode, loading `kitchen table.blend`, and running the script using the custom argument after the `--`

However, when I try to do the same from Python I can't get Blender to digest the `--python` argument. Not as `-P` nor anything else, like `--python-text`.

Any insights?

I run a Python command like:

```
subprocess.run(['C:/Program Files/Blender Foundation/Blender 3.6/blender.exe', 'kitchen table.blend', '--background', '--python animate_book.py', '-- ' + chapter.title_filename + '.csv'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Blender 3.6.0 (hash c7fc78b81ecb built 2023-06-27 08:27:30)
Read prefs: "C:\Users\████████\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\config\userpref.blend"
Read blend: "D:\Documents\Programming\████████\kitchen table.blend"
unknown argument, loading as file: --python animate_book.py
Error: Cannot read file "D:\Documents\Programming\████████\--python animate_book.py": No such file or directory
```

I've looked around a bit, and found [Blender doesn't recognize --python as a command line argument](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267812/blender-doesnt-recognize-python-as-a-command-line-argument), but I don't seem to have the same problem? And it works from the command line already, just not from the Python subprocess.run() call?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps separate `--python` and the scrip file name in different quotes, as shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70771/53447)?

Comment: OMG, I'm a knob... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a test script on my own:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run([
    'C:/AppInstall/Blender/stable/blender-4.0.0+stable.878f71061b8e/blender.exe',
    'C:/tmp/test.blend',
    '--background',
    '--python',
    'C:/tmp/script.py'
    ])
```

Using two declarations for `--python-`  and `C:/tmp/script.py` works, while combining them as one `--python C:/tmp/script.py` doesn't.